# TensorBoard costant spikes on gradients distributions

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, distribution, tensorboard

I'm training a custom short network with Keras (2.1.6) and Tensorflow (1.4.0) as backend. While training, I use the tensorboard callback as:

```
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir=OUTPUT_PATH,
    histogram_freq=EPOCH_STEPS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    write_grads=True)
```

This produces the expected results, but when I lok at the gradients distributions on TensorBoard, I see weird things on the graphs, which repeat at the same step of the `histogram_freq` variable.

For example, for `histogram_freq=1` and a convolution layer with 1 kernel (1,1) the distributions are:
[image]
[image]

In both images you can see spikes with interval 1.
As additional information, the network being trained works on images of resolution 320x200 and the output is a full image 320x200 which get's compared with it's label (segmentation).
Maybe the problem is that?

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but looks like the gradients go crazy at the start of each epoch, so maybe you accidentally run `tf.global_variables_initializer()` at the beginning of every epoch?

Do the weight distributions show the same pattern?

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer, I'm using Keras and the weights distributions seem to keep updating. I will try to make a super small example into which other people can see the same behavior? Maybe that would explain it.

Comment: Ok, that's a great idea!

Comment: Here I opened an issue on the Keras github (I think it's related to that): https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10059.

Comment: Idea: what if you don't do validation at all? Can you test like that? Maybe validation messes something up.

Comment: The other thing possible is [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L137) resetting things at the start of each epoch.

Comment: Very very intresting, Ill try without validation.